# Scroll Pane is visible but doesn't work when dynamically updating rows in java table

Tags: java, jscrollpane

I have a java table where i update rows dynamically. Here is an example which i created. It mimics my actual program line by line for creating table and adding scrollpane. My actual program is huge and sorry i can't share it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
class SimpleTableExample extends JFrame
{
private JPanel      topPanel;
private JTable      table;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private DefaultTableModel model = null;
private JPanel pMainMenu = null;
public SimpleTableExample()
{

    pMainMenu = new JPanel();
    BorderLayout thisLayout = new BorderLayout();
    pMainMenu.setLayout(thisLayout);
    {
        JPanel pButtons = new JPanel();
        pMainMenu.add(pButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        GridBagLayout pButtonsLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        pButtonsLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{7, 7, 7};
        pButtonsLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{25};
        pButtonsLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
        pButtonsLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.1};
        {
            JButton btNew = new JButton();
            pButtons.add(btNew, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                    new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            btNew.setText("<html><center>Run</center><center>Configuration</center></html>");
            btNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    btRunConfiguration(evt);
                }
            });
        }
    }




    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    {
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table = new JTable(model);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        model.addColumn(" ");
        model.addColumn(" ");
        model.addColumn(" ");
    }

    getContentPane().add(pMainMenu);
    getContentPane().repaint();
    pack();
    setSize(520, 130);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);


}

private void btRunConfiguration(ActionEvent evt) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add( topPanel );
    getContentPane().repaint();

    setTitle("Simple Table Application");
    setSize(300, 100);
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

    for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            // ignore!
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addRow(new Object[]{i,i,i});
        /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/
        //Must schedule the close before the dialog becomes visible
        JFrame closeDialog = new JFrame();
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(closeDialog, "Updated", true);

        ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        s.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dialog.setVisible(false); //should be invoked on the EDT
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        }, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        dialog.setVisible(true); // if modal, application will pause here

        //System.out.println("Dialog closed");
        /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/

    }
}


public static void main( String args[] )
{
    // Create an instance of the test application
    SimpleTableExample mainFrame    = new SimpleTableExample();
    mainFrame.setVisible( true );
}
}
```

Scroll pane doesn't work. Can you please help. Thanks

***************************New Code***************************************

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
 import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
 class SimpleTableExample extends JFrame
 {
 private JPanel      topPanel;
private JTable      table;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private DefaultTableModel model = null;
private JPanel pMainMenu = null;
public SimpleTableExample()
{

    pMainMenu = new JPanel();
    BorderLayout thisLayout = new BorderLayout();
    pMainMenu.setLayout(thisLayout);
    {
        JPanel pButtons = new JPanel();
        pMainMenu.add(pButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        GridBagLayout pButtonsLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        pButtonsLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{7, 7, 7};
        pButtonsLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{25};
        pButtonsLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
        pButtonsLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.1};
        {
            JButton btNew = new JButton();
            pButtons.add(btNew, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                    new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            btNew.setText("<html><center>Run</center><center>Configuration</center></html>");
            btNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    btRunConfiguration(evt);
                }
            });
        }
    }




    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    {
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table = new JTable(model);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        model.addColumn(" ");
        model.addColumn(" ");
        model.addColumn(" ");
    }

    getContentPane().add(pMainMenu);
    getContentPane().repaint();
    pack();
    setSize(520, 130);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);


}

private void btRunConfiguration(ActionEvent evt) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add( topPanel );
    getContentPane().repaint();

    setTitle("Simple Table Application");
    setSize(300, 100);
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

    for(int i=0;i<300;i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            // ignore!
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        new MyWorker(model).execute();
        /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/
        //Must schedule the close before the dialog becomes visible
        JFrame closeDialog = new JFrame();
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(closeDialog, "Updated", true);

        ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                dialog.setVisible(false); //should be invoked on the EDT
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(500, timerAction);
        timer.start();
        dialog.setVisible(true); // if modal, application will pause here

        //System.out.println("Dialog closed");
        /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/
    }
}
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    DefaultTableModel model;
    MyWorker(DefaultTableModel model){
        this.model=model;
    }
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
     model.addRow(new Object[]{1,1,1});
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {

    }
}


public static void main( String args[] )
{
    // Create an instance of the test application
    SimpleTableExample mainFrame    = new SimpleTableExample();
    mainFrame.setVisible( true );
}}
```

*************************************New Code 2 Timer Problem*******************

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
class SimpleTableExample extends JFrame
{
private JPanel      topPanel;
private JTable      table;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private DefaultTableModel model = null;
private JPanel pMainMenu = null;
private Timer timer = null;
public SimpleTableExample()
{

    pMainMenu = new JPanel();
    BorderLayout thisLayout = new BorderLayout();
    pMainMenu.setLayout(thisLayout);
    {
        JPanel pButtons = new JPanel();
        pMainMenu.add(pButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        GridBagLayout pButtonsLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        pButtonsLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{7, 7, 7};
        pButtonsLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{25};
        pButtonsLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
        pButtonsLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.1};
        {
            JButton btNew = new JButton();
            pButtons.add(btNew, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                    new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            btNew.setText("<html><center>Run</center><center>Configuration</center></html>");
            btNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    btRunConfiguration(evt);
                }
            });
        }
    }




    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    {
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table = new JTable(model);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        model.addColumn(" ");
        model.addColumn(" ");
        model.addColumn(" ");
    }

    getContentPane().add(pMainMenu);
    getContentPane().repaint();
    pack();
    setSize(520, 130);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

    String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

    //new MyWorker().execute();


}

private void btRunConfiguration(ActionEvent evt) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add( topPanel );
    getContentPane().repaint();

    setTitle("Simple Table Application");
    setSize(300, 100);
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    pack();
    showOnScreen(1,this);
    setVisible(true);
    new MyWorker().execute();

}
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {



    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {


        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
                    try {
                        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                        rt.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        // ignore!
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException le) {
                        le.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{i, i, i});
                    /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/
                    //Must schedule the close before the dialog becomes visible
                    JFrame closeDialog = new JFrame();
                    final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(closeDialog, "Updated", true);

                    ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                    s.schedule(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.setVisible(false); //should be invoked on the EDT
                            dialog.dispose();
                        }
                    }, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                    dialog.setVisible(true); // if modal, application will pause here

                    //System.out.println("Dialog closed");
                    /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/

                }
            }
        };


        timer = new Timer(20, taskPerformer);

        timer.start();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {

    }
}



public static void main( String args[] )
{
    // Create an instance of the test application
    SimpleTableExample mainFrame    = new SimpleTableExample();
    mainFrame.setVisible( true );
}

public void showOnScreen( int screen, JFrame frame ) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
    if( screen > 0 && screen < 2 ) {
        int x = frame.getWidth()/2;
        int y = frame.getHeight()/2;
        frame.setLocation((gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().width * 3/2) - x,   (gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().height *1/2) - y);
        // JFrame dummy = new JFrame(gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration());
        // setLocationRelativeTo(dummy);
        // dummy.dispose();
    } else if( gd.length > 0 ) {
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what problem are you having with the ScrollPane?Can you explain a little further.For me its working fine on my mac.

Comment: At my side the scroll doesn't work. It is visible and as rows increase the scroll updates but it doesn't move when i click with mouse on it. I want it to work while the rows are being updated not until it finishes because my actual program never ends.

Comment: Ok got your point while updating its not moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use swing threads when interacting with swing components.Try the below solution it works

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
class SimpleTableExample extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel      topPanel;
    private JTable      table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private DefaultTableModel model = null;
    private JPanel pMainMenu = null;
    public SimpleTableExample()
    {

    pMainMenu = new JPanel();
    BorderLayout thisLayout = new BorderLayout();
    pMainMenu.setLayout(thisLayout);
    {
        JPanel pButtons = new JPanel();
        pMainMenu.add(pButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        GridBagLayout pButtonsLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        pButtonsLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{7, 7, 7};
        pButtonsLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{25};
        pButtonsLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
        pButtonsLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.1};
        {
            JButton btNew = new JButton();
            pButtons.add(btNew, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                    new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            btNew.setText("<html><center>Run</center><center>Configuration</center></html>");
            btNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    btRunConfiguration(evt);
                }
            });
        }
    }




    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    {
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table = new JTable(model);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        model.addColumn(" ");
        model.addColumn(" ");
        model.addColumn(" ");
    }

    getContentPane().add(pMainMenu);
    getContentPane().repaint();
    pack();
    setSize(520, 130);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);


}

private void btRunConfiguration(ActionEvent evt) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add( topPanel );
    getContentPane().repaint();

    setTitle("Simple Table Application");
    setSize(300, 100);
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

    new MyWorker(model).execute();
}
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    DefaultTableModel model;
    MyWorker(DefaultTableModel model){
        this.model=model;
    }
    @Override
       public Void doInBackground() {
        for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                // ignore!
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
            model.addRow(new Object[]{i,i,i});
            /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/
            //Must schedule the close before the dialog becomes visible
            JFrame closeDialog = new JFrame();
            final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(closeDialog, "Updated", true);

             ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    dialog.setVisible(false); //should be invoked on the EDT
                    dialog.dispose();
                }
            };
            Timer timer = new Timer(500, timerAction);
            timer.start();
            dialog.setVisible(true); // if modal, application will pause here

            //System.out.println("Dialog closed");
            /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/

        }
          return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void done() {

       }
   }


public static void main( String args[] )
{
    // Create an instance of the test application
    SimpleTableExample mainFrame    = new SimpleTableExample();
    mainFrame.setVisible( true );
}}
```

**UPDATE**
According to your problem that you updated with your design.You just have to make sure the loop needs to run through a Swing Thread.For example if you have this method of update table

```
private void updateTable(){
 for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            // ignore!
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addRow(new Object[]{i,i,i});
        /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/
        //Must schedule the close before the dialog becomes visible
        JFrame closeDialog = new JFrame();
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(closeDialog, "Updated", true);

        ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        s.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dialog.setVisible(false); //should be invoked on the EDT
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        }, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        dialog.setVisible(true); // if modal, application will pause here

        //System.out.println("Dialog closed");
        /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/

    }}
```

Make sure you call it from SwingWorker

```
private void btRunConfiguration(ActionEvent evt) {
getContentPane().removeAll();
getContentPane().add( topPanel );
getContentPane().repaint();

setTitle("Simple Table Application");
setSize(300, 100);
setBackground(Color.gray);
pack();
setVisible(true);
  new MyWorker().execute();

}
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {



@Override
public Void doInBackground() {

     updateTable();
return null;
}

@Override
protected void done() {

} }
```

**According to update 2**

```
private void btRunConfiguration(ActionEvent evt) {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().add( topPanel );
        getContentPane().repaint();

        setTitle("Simple Table Application");
        setSize(300, 100);
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        pack();
        showOnScreen(1,this);
        setVisible(true);
        final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!flag.get()){
                    flag.set(true);
                    new MyWorker(flag).execute();
                    //flag.set(false);
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();

    }
    class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        AtomicBoolean flag;
        MyWorker(AtomicBoolean flag){
            this.flag=flag;
        }

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {

            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
                try {
                    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                    rt.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    // ignore!
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception le) {
                    le.printStackTrace();
                }
                model.addRow(new Object[]{i, i, i});
                /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/
                //Must schedule the close before the dialog becomes visible
                JFrame closeDialog = new JFrame();
                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(closeDialog, "Updated", true);

                ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                s.schedule(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        dialog.setVisible(false); //should be invoked on the EDT
                        dialog.dispose();
                    }
                }, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                dialog.setVisible(true); // if modal, application will pause here

                //System.out.println("Dialog closed");
                /**************This message dialog box show row updated to refresh table for viewing***********/

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            flag.set(false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I am trying to apply this to my original code. Will work on it and get back to you if i face any issues.

Comment: I have my loop and array values being updated in other classes. I can't move them. Is it possible to update only the view/rows of table from this thread. I tried my best to replicate with the "New code" i posted above. Can you please review. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help. I got your point. Was able to do with the sample above you provided. But it still doesn't work with my actual program. Actually, the program opens a browser with image, takes a screenshot, does some processing with the image, gets result, updates row in table and writes to file. There are many things happening. Basically there are two active windows running. The browser and the table view in two different screens. Can you give your valuable opinion please. Thanks.

Comment: @user2100513 Not sure how much I can help without codes.I'll just advice avoid heavy processing and run heavy processing task in different worker thread so that your UI thread doesn't get blocked or unresponsive

Comment: Hi Sarfaraaz..Sorry to trouble you again...But i think i found out finally why it wasn't working....Please take a look at the sample program above. Its because of a timer which reruns the program every 20 seconds. I am certain because my actual program was responsive when i removed this timer. Can you please help now. Thanks again. I appreciate your response.

Comment: @user2100513 your above code works fine if you just remove `ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {` and run your loop directly in doInBackground() method

Comment: I understand that...But i need to run that loop again and again with a timer....I used a ScheduledExecutorService instead of timer and it did solve that issue with the UI thing although my table rendering is acting weird...Anyhow that;s a different issue...Thanks again so much for helping me out.

Comment: @user2100513 took me a while but finally found a solution check my Update 2 section ...Hope this will solve you issue.. :)

Comment: Amazing...Awesome...It works perfect...I don't even have the rendering issue any more...Thank you so so so much. You are the best  :-)